# C++ CodeBlocks disassembly; Way too much code?

Tags: c++, assembly, x86

I ran the debugger on CodeBlocks and viewed the disassembly window.

The full source code for the program I debugged is the following:

```
int main(){}
```

and the assembly code I saw in the window was this:

```
00401020    push   %ebp
00401021    mov    %esp,%ebp
00401023    push   %ebx
00401024    sub    $0x34,%esp
00401027    movl   $0x401150,(%esp)
0040102E    call   0x401984 <SetUnhandledExceptionFilter@4>
00401033    sub    $0x4,%esp
00401036    call   0x401330 <__cpu_features_init>
0040103B    call   0x401740 <fpreset>
00401040    lea    -0x10(%ebp),%eax
00401043    movl   $0x0,-0x10(%ebp)
0040104A    mov    %eax,0x10(%esp)
0040104E    mov    0x402000,%eax
00401053    movl   $0x404004,0x4(%esp)
0040105B    movl   $0x404000,(%esp)
00401062    mov    %eax,0xc(%esp)
00401066    lea    -0xc(%ebp),%eax
00401069    mov    %eax,0x8(%esp)
0040106D    call   0x40192c <__getmainargs>
00401072    mov    0x404008,%eax
00401077    test   %eax,%eax
00401079    jne    0x4010c5 <__mingw_CRTStartup+165>
0040107B    call   0x401934 <__p__fmode>
00401080    mov    0x402004,%edx
00401086    mov    %edx,(%eax)
00401088    call   0x4014f0 <_pei386_runtime_relocator>
0040108D    and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
00401090    call   0x401720 <__main>
00401095    call   0x40193c <__p__environ>
0040109A    mov    (%eax),%eax
0040109C    mov    %eax,0x8(%esp)
004010A0    mov    0x404004,%eax
004010A5    mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
004010A9    mov    0x404000,%eax
004010AE    mov    %eax,(%esp)
004010B1    call   0x401318 <main>
004010B6    mov    %eax,%ebx
004010B8    call   0x401944 <_cexit>
004010BD    mov    %ebx,(%esp)
004010C0    call   0x40198c <ExitProcess@4>
004010C5    mov    0x4050f4,%ebx
004010CB    mov    %eax,0x402004
004010D0    mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
004010D4    mov    0x10(%ebx),%eax
004010D7    mov    %eax,(%esp)
004010DA    call   0x40194c <_setmode>
004010DF    mov    0x404008,%eax
004010E4    mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
004010E8    mov    0x30(%ebx),%eax
004010EB    mov    %eax,(%esp)
004010EE    call   0x40194c <_setmode>
004010F3    mov    0x404008,%eax
004010F8    mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
004010FC    mov    0x50(%ebx),%eax
004010FF    mov    %eax,(%esp)
00401102    call   0x40194c <_setmode>
00401107    jmp    0x40107b <__mingw_CRTStartup+91>
0040110C    lea    0x0(%esi,%eiz,1),%esi
```

Is it normal to get this much assembly code from so little C++ code?

By normal, I mean is this close to the average amount of assembly code the MinGW compiler generates relative to the amount of C++ source code I provided above?

Comment: MinGW sticks extra stuff into `main` itself, instead of having init functions run before `main` like on Linux.  See https://godbolt.org/z/ardd6qbYn for un-optimized vs. optimized `gcc -m32` targeting Linux.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes, this is fairly typical startup/shutdown code.

Before your `main` runs, a few things need to happen:

1. stdin/stdout/stderr get opened
2. cin/cout/cerr/clog get opened, referring to stdin/stdout/stderr
3. Any static objects you define get initialized
4. command line gets parsed to produce argc/argv
5. environment gets retrieved (maybe)

Likewise, after your `main` exits, a few more things have to happen:

1. Anything set up with `atexit` gets run
2. Your static objects get destroyed
3. cin/cout/cerr/clog get destroyed
4. all open output streams get flushed and closed
5. all open input streams get closed

Depending on the platform, there may be a few more things as well, such as setting up some default exception handlers (for either C++ exceptions, some platform-specific exceptions, or both).

Note that most of this is fixed code that gets linked into essentially *every* program, regardless of what it does or doesn't contain. In theory, they can use some tricks (e.g., "weak externals") to avoid linking in some of this code when it isn't needed, but most of what's above is used so close to universally (and the code to handle it is sufficiently trivial) that it's pretty rare to bother going to any work to eliminate this little bit of code, even when it's not going to be used (like your case, where nothing gets used at all).

Note that what you've shown *is* startup/shutdown code though. It's linked into your program, traditionally from a file named something like `crt0` (along with, perhaps, some additional files).

If you look through your file for the code generated for `main` itself, you'll probably find that it's a lot shorter--possibly as short and simple as just `ret`. It may be so tiny that you missed the fact that it's there at all though.

Comment: Thank you this is the perfect explanation! Now all I need is an explanation for the semi-hostility generated by my question :)

Comment: There are a couple of factors at work there, I'd guess. First of all, a lot of questions that are seen as "too easy" generate hostility, even if they're things that aren't easy to search for. Second, quite a few people tend to think only in terms of whether something works, not *how* it works, and tend to steer others away from paying attention to those details either.

Comment: That certainly narrows it down. If not for your answers, I would have been left in a mood too sour. Thanks for your time and take care.

Answer (score 2):

This `call   0x401318 <main>`

is what you code resolved to,  basically.  main() is a function and there is code surrounding it, often called something like `__start` and `__end`.

What you see amounts, in part, to the CRT support code in __start, and cleanup afterward in __end.